# Python imports issue

Tags: python, import

I have a Utilities module which defines a few functions which are repeatedly used and am also adding in some constants.  I'm running into trouble importing these constants though...

Let's say I'm working in class A, and I have a class in my constants also named A

```
from Utils.Constants import A as DistinctA
class A(object):
    .... Implementation ....
    some_var = DistinctA.SOME_CONSTANT

class Utils(object):
  class Constants(object):
    class A(object):
      SOME_CONSTANT = "Constant"
```

I'm probably making this too much like Java, so if so just yell / smack my knuckles with a ruler.

When I attempt to import that class, I get an error that there is no module named Constants.  What's this python newbie missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The identifier after 'from' must point to a module; you can't refer to a class.  While I'm not qualified to say whether your nested classes are 'pythonic', I have never seen it done like that before.  I'd be more inclined to create a constants.py module that contains the `A` class.  Then you could do this:

```
from constants import A as DistinctA
```

If you really want those constants to live inside utils, you could make utils a package:

```
utils/
utils/__init__.py
utils/constants.py
```

Then you can do:

```
from utils.constants import A as DistinctA
```